# Javascript distinct list of object properties

Tags: javascript, object, properties, distinct

How do I create a list of distinct properties from a javascript object?

Here is a sample string, this string is created dynamically (I dont know what properties and values it may contain.

```js
[{
  "ID": 331,
  "DynamicString": "",
  "MyDate": "",
  "TestCheckbox": "false",
  "TestTA": "",
  "BusinessCategory": "Regulatory",
  "PriorityGroup": "Must Do"
}, {
  "ID": 335,
  "DynamicString": "hjkhjkhjk",
  "MyDate": "17/02/2016",
  "TestCheckbox": "true",
  "TestTA": "hjkhjkhjk",
  "BusinessCategory": "Regulatory",
  "PriorityGroup": "Should Do"
}, {
  "ID": 336,
  "DynamicString": "What about this",
  "MyDate": "26/05/2016",
  "TestCheckbox": "false",
  "TestTA": "What about this",
  "BusinessCategory": "Machinery of Government",
  "PriorityGroup": "Should Do"
}]
```

I would like the output to be

> "ID", "DynamicString", "MyDate", "TestCheckBox", "TestTA", "BusinessCategory", "PriorityGroup"

I pass the data into an object, but am unsure of the best way to loop through and create a distinct list of properties.

Comment: has every item the same properties?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this

```
var arr = [{"ID":331,"DynamicString":"","MyDate":"","TestCheckbox":"false","TestTA":"","BusinessCategory":"Regulatory","PriorityGroup":"Must Do"},{"ID":335,"DynamicString":"hjkhjkhjk","MyDate":"17/02/2016","TestCheckbox":"true","TestTA":"hjkhjkhjk","BusinessCategory":"Regulatory","PriorityGroup":"Should Do"},{"ID":336,"DynamicString":"What about this","MyDate":"26/05/2016","TestCheckbox":"false","TestTA":"What about this","BusinessCategory":"Machinery of Government","PriorityGroup":"Should Do"}];
function arrayUnique(array) 
{
    var a = array.concat();
    for(var i=0; i<a.length; ++i) 
    {
        for(var j=i+1; j<a.length; ++j) 
        {
            if(a[i] === a[j])
                a.splice(j--, 1);
        }
    }
    return a;
}
var output = [];
arr.forEach( function(value){ output = output.concat( Object.keys( value ) ) } );//concatenate all the items
console.log ( arrayUnique(output) ); //print the unique elements
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys):

> The `Object.keys()` method returns an array of a given object's own enumerable properties, in the same order as that provided by a [`for ... in`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...in) loop (the difference being that a for-in loop enumerates properties in the prototype chain as well).

If the array items have the same properties, then this will work:

```
var properties = Object.keys(Array[0]);
```

If not the this will help with iterating over all objects and their keys.

```js
var array = [{ "ID": 331, "DynamicString": "", "MyDate": "", "TestCheckbox": "false", "TestTA": "", "BusinessCategory": "Regulatory", "PriorityGroup": "Must Do" }, { "ID": 335, "DynamicString": "hjkhjkhjk", "MyDate": "17/02/2016", "TestCheckbox": "true", "TestTA": "hjkhjkhjk", "BusinessCategory": "Regulatory", "PriorityGroup": "Should Do" }, { "ID": 336, "DynamicString": "What about this", "MyDate": "26/05/2016", "TestCheckbox": "false", "TestTA": "What about this", "BusinessCategory": "Machinery of Government", "PriorityGroup": "Should Do" }],
    properties = function (array) {
        var o = {};
        array.forEach(function (a) {
            Object.keys(a).forEach(function (k) {
                o[k] = true;
            });
        });
        return Object.keys(o);
    }(array);

document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(Object.keys(array[0]), 0, 4) + '</pre>');
document.write('<pre>' + JSON.stringify(properties, 0, 4) + '</pre>');
```